# WYSIWYG Editor for Mathematical Equations using MathJax

Tags: javascript, jquery, math, mathjax

I am trying to build **WYSIWYG Editor to write Mathematical Formulas using MathJax**. I am trying to select random content from the textarea and pasting it into a div for converting it into a Mathematical Equations.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Wrap Selected Content with Dummy Editor</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML"></script>;
    <script type="text/x-mathjax-config">
        MathJax.Hub.Config({tex2jax: { inlineMath: [ ['$','$'], ['\\(','\\)'] ] } });
        MathJax.Hub.Config({tex2jax: { displayMath: [ ['$$','$$'], ['\\(','\\)'] ] } });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<!--Select some random text from this textarea and click button -->
<textarea id="wrapSelectedContent"></textarea>
<!-- Content should be load here using JavaScript and Convert it into Mathematical Function -->
<div id="pasteSelectedContent" style="width:300px; height:300px; border:2px solid #000;"></div>
<!-- Static Content displayed Successfully -->
<p>$$\sum(a+b)(c+d)$$</p>
<button onclick="wrapContent();">Put Summation Sign</button>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function wrapContent(){
        var selectedContent = document.getElementById("wrapSelectedContent");
        var pasteselectedContent = document.getElementById("pasteSelectedContent");
        var textlength = selectedContent.textLength;
        var start = selectedContent.selectionStart;
        var end = selectedContent.selectionEnd;
        selectedContent.focus();
        selectedContent.setSelectionRange(start,end); 
        var selectedContentValue = selectedContent.value.substring(start, end);
        var replace = "$$\\sum" + selectedContentValue + "$$";
        pasteselectedContent.textContent = selectedContent.value.substring(0,start) + " " + replace + " " + selectedContent.value.substring(end,textlength);        
        console.log("Start Index : " + start);
        console.log("End Index : " + end);
        console.log("Text Content Length : " + textlength);
        console.log(selectedContentValue);
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

**So how can i convert the text displayed in div#pasteSelectedContent with Mathematical Equations
Please help me to build this WYSIWYG Editor**

Comment: "Please help me [do my entire project]" really doesn't turn out well here.  Can you specify what exactly you're having trouble with?  Selecting content in a textarea?  Pasting it to the div?  Parsing the text to understand it?  Printing the parsed text as math?  If it's all of these, then you've bitten off more than you can chew.

Comment: @Teepeemm i was having problem for parsing text into mathematical eq. which is solved as the answer given by me

Comment: Note from the future: cdn.mathjax.org is nearing its end-of-life, check https://mathjax.org/cdn-shutting-down for migration tips.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Problem Solved**

just insert

```
    MathJax.Hub.Queue(["Typeset", MathJax.Hub, "pasteselectedContent"]);
```

after line 32

```
pasteselectedContent.textContent = selectedContent.value.substring(0,start) + " " + replace + " " + selectedContent.value.substring(end,textlength);
```