# Mathjax insert div write text ContentEditable div?

Tags: javascript, html, mathjax

i reference [WYSIWYG Editor for Mathematical Equations using MathJax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28452359/) this Code

this code is here

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<head>
    <title>mathjx</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML"></script>;
    <script type="text/x-mathjax-config">
        MathJax.Hub.Config({tex2jax: { inlineMath: [ ['\\','\\'], ['\\(','\\)'] ] } });
        MathJax.Hub.Config({tex2jax: { displayMath: [ ['$$','$$'], ['\\(','\\)'] ] } });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<!--Select some random text from this textarea and click button -->
<textarea id="wrapSelectedContent"></textarea>
<!-- Content should be load here using JavaScript and Convert it into Mathematical Function -->
<div id="pasteSelectedContent" contenteditable="true" style="width:300px; height:300px; border:2px solid #000;"></div>
<!-- Static Content displayed Successfully -->
<button onclick="wrapContent();">ConVert</button>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function wrapContent(){
        var selectedContent = document.getElementById("wrapSelectedContent");
        var pasteselectedContent = document.getElementById("pasteSelectedContent");
        var textlength = selectedContent.textLength;
        var start = selectedContent.selectionStart;
        var end = selectedContent.selectionEnd;
        selectedContent.focus();
        selectedContent.setSelectionRange(start,end); 
        var selectedContentValue = selectedContent.value.substring(start, end); 
        var replace = "$$" + selectedContentValue + "$$";
        pasteselectedContent.textContent = selectedContent.value.substring(0,start) + selectedContent.value.substring(end,textlength); 
        MathJax.Hub.Queue(["Typeset", MathJax.Hub, "pasteselectedContent"]);

    }
</script>   
</body>
</html>
```

code is working very well.

now, I want change 
`<textarea id="wrapSelectedContent">` => `<div contenteditable="true">` tag.

i change a div code. but script error. 
"wh_test.html:27 Uncaught TypeError: selectedContent.setSelectionRange is not a function"

How does it work change this code.. Thanks for reading.

Comment: Note from the future: cdn.mathjax.org is nearing its end-of-life, check https://www.mathjax.org/cdn-shutting-down/ for migration tips.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***Firstly*** use the same **ID** in *contenteditable* div. Therefore
`<textarea id="wrapSelectedContent"></textarea>` needs to be changed into `<div id="wrapSelectedContent" contenteditable="true"></div>` tag.

***Secondly*** div has no value property you have to use **innerHTML** to get similar results as for textarea.
Thus following
`var selectedContentValue = selectedContent.value.substring(start, end);`
have to be changed into `var selectedContentValue = selectedContent.innerHTML.substring(start, end);`

Comment: i agree, note <div> has html inside and not pure text