# Rendering math formulas with MathJax using TinyMCE

Tags: javascript, tinymce-4, mathjax

I'm facing an issue while I'm trying to render a math formula inside WYSIWYG editor based on TinyMCE.

**The code**

Here the initialisation of TinyMCE

```
$(document).ready(function () {

  $('body').html(`<div id="raje_root">${$('body').html()}</div>`)

  tinymce.init({

    selector: '#raje_root',

    content_css: ['css/bootstrap.min.css', 'css/rash.css', 'css/rajemce.css'],

    plugins: "fullscreen link codesample raje_inlineCode raje_inlineQuote raje_section table image noneditable raje_figure raje_table raje_listing raje_formula preview",

    menubar: false,

    toolbar: 'undo redo bold italic link superscript subscript raje_inlineCode raje_inlineQuote | codesample blockquote raje_table raje_figure raje_listing raje_formula | raje_section preview',

    setup: function (editor) {

    editor.on('init', function (e) {

      editor.execCommand('mceFullScreen')
    })
  })
})
```

Instead, here MathJax initialisation (**config:** TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML)

```
var ignore_math_class = 'rash-nomath';
var process_math_class = 'rash-math';

var ascii_math_left_delimiter = '``';
var ascii_math_right_delimiter = '``';

var tex_math_left_delimiter = '$$';
var tex_math_right_delimiter = '$$';

MathJax.Hub.Config({

  asciimath2jax: {

    delimiters: [ [ascii_math_left_delimiter, ascii_math_right_delimiter] ],
      processClass: process_math_class,
      ignoreClass: ignore_math_class
    },
    tex2jax: {

      inlineMath: [ [tex_math_left_delimiter, tex_math_right_delimiter] ],
      processClass: process_math_class,
      ignoreClass: ignore_math_class
    }
  }
});
```

This is **index.html** body

```
<body>
<section id="section1">
  <h1>Parent section</h1>
  <figure id="formula_2">
  <p>
    <math xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML">
      <mrow>
        <msup>
          <mfenced open="[" close="]">
            <mrow>
              <mi>a</mi>
              <mo>+</mo>
              <mi>b</mi>
            </mrow>
          </mfenced>
          <mn>260</mn>
        </msup>
        <mo>+</mo>
        <msub>
          <mfenced open="{" close="}">
            <mrow>
              <mi>a</mi>
              <mo>+</mo>
              <mi>b</mi>
            </mrow>
          </mfenced>
          <mi>i</mi>
        </msub>
      </mrow>
    </math>
  </p>
</figure>
```

**The problem**

Normally (outside from TinyMCE) it should be rendered as follow (the caption is not important, is just a number to locate formula inside the document)
[image: How MathJax formula should be rendered]

Instead of this behaviour, TinyMCE transform it into raw text in a paragraph like this[image]

**The answer**

in other words: **Somehow TinyMCE prevent MathJax formulas to be rendered**.

**NOTE:** This happens also with other inputs (LaTeX, AsciiMath)

How can i configure these plugins in order to render formulas between TinyMCE boundaries?

Comment: perhaps a start here? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28452359/wysiwyg-editor-for-mathematical-equations-using-mathjax

Comment: Thank you, but this is not helping with TinyMCE

Comment: Yes, I have no joy with TinyMCE yet. I have something working with CKEditor and mathjax. You can just use the basic editor and add the plugins/functionality you want here http://ckeditor.com/builder

Comment: did you find any solution ? I am looking for it too.